# Why is the number of FPs less than reported positives in this case?

Tags: multiple-comparisons

From [page 17 of some slides](http://www.statistik.uni-dortmund.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Lehrstuehle/Genetik/BS1213/Biostatistik_mit_R_Borg.pdf), In multiple comparison, when "not all null hypotheses are true", why is the number of false positives $V$ less than the the number of reported positives $R$, i.e. $V < R$? There can still be true positive(s), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking about $V=R$ then it is indeed a possibility. There is no reason all rejections can't be false when "not all null hypotheses are true".

Comment: Thanks! when "not all null hypotheses are true", why is the number of false positives V less than the the number of reported positives R, i.e. V<R?

Comment: my point is that that statement seems false.

Comment: I also think the slides is wrong.